# When I pressed setState function, numbers are not adding

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

On numbers are not adding when I press the calculate button

Variable I took

```
String _bmi = "0";
```

Here's the code portion

```
     OutlinedButton(
        child: Text('Calculate',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            color: kTitleTextColor,
          ),
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            int sum = int.parse(massNumber.text) + int.parse(heightNumber.text);
            _bmi = sum.toString();
          });
        },
      ),
      Text(_bmi,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: kTitleTextColor,
          fontSize: 18.0,
        ),
      ),
```

Please help

Comment: Check if all values are correct. Is `massNumber.text` correct? Is `heightNumber.text` correct? Is `_bmi` correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your function works fine. I have added a dummy data function below so you can see it. So either you have an error with your data that comes, maybe the are null or empty or not integer or you have another error in your console.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

refer this example

```
void main()

{
  double num = 0;
  String wight = "40";
  String height = "20";
  double sum = double.parse(wight) + double.parse(height);
  num = sum;
  print(num.toString());
}
```

[https://dartpad.dev/?](https://Run%20to%20Check)

Answer (score 0):

The code using `setState()` is working correctly.
Try it out.

```
int sum = int.parse(massNumber.text) + int.parse(heightNumber.text);
```

is replaced to ↓

```
int sum = int.parse("1") + int.parse("2");
```

and run it, it works correctly.

Are the numbers in `massNumber.text` and `heightNumber.text` correct?